# Show that the sequence of functions $f_n(x)=xe^{-nx}$ for $x\in(0,1)$ converges pointwise to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, uniform-convergence

Is it enough to calculate $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} xe^{-nx}$ or should we analyze it more carefully?

Comment: It is enough, and basic.

Comment: Any constraints on $n$?

Comment: Given that that's the definition of pointwise convergence, that's fine.

Comment: @T.Bongers What do you mean with "that's the definition of pointwise convergence"?

Comment: That $\lim_{n \to \infty} xe^{-nx} = 0$ for every $x$ is exactly what "pointwise convergent to zero" means.

Comment: @JellyBelly "$(f_n)_n$ converges pointwise to $f$ on $I$ if, for every fixed $x_0\in I$, $$f_n(x_0) \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} f(x_0)."$$

Comment: @ClementC. you too :)